# Add trusted remote certificate to Ubuntu server

Tags: certificate, sftp

I'm running an app on an AWS server running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. I'm writing a script to connect to an SFTP server from the command line, but am unable to connect.

I believe this is because my Ubuntu server does not trust the certificate on the SFTP server I'm trying to connect to.  The reason I believe this is the case is because when I use a desktop program like Filezilla to manually connect to the SFTP server, Filezilla first warns me that the server's certificate is unknown, and I need to confirm that I would like to trust the certificate and continue connecting. After doing so, I am successfully connected.

When I try to connect programmatically from a script on the Ubunut server, I get errors that the connection is unsuccessful and has timed out.  I'm hoping someone can confirm whether or not I am correct to think this could be the cause of the problem, and instruct me on how I can ensure my Ubuntu server trusts the certificates on the remote SFTP server.

I am attempting to connect to: ftps://feeds.adcenter.microsoft.com.

Comment: Further investigation shows that the certificate chains to Baltimore CyberTrust Root, which from what I can tell, is part of the standard OpenSSL installation. So, I'm think my server should be trusting the certificate and this is therefore not what's causing the problem. If anyone can confirm or deny this that would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try specifying the key to use with `-i` ?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the output of the commands you have tried.  `cat` any scripts or configs that might relate as long as it doesn't include your password or something.

Comment: The specifics depends on the library/utility/scripting language you're using. Please include those. -  Typically increasing the verbosity and displaying long errors should point you in the right direction.